# Slice time in single element in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, slice

The first column of my data frame has the following format

```
Sciospec['Time']
0      12:29:50:496
1      12:31:02:082
```

And so forth.

I would like to get rid of whatever comes after the last colon. In other words:

```
Sciospec['Time']
0      12:29:50
1      12:31:02
```

I tried searching for slicing command but, to the best my knowledge, it is not used for a single element. I wonder if anyone can help me on this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
Sciospec['Time']=Sciospec['Time'].str.rsplit(':',1).str[0]
```

Comment: @NavidRashedi it will pick the sep , and split by it from the right , but it will stop for the first sep (1 here), then we pick it put for the first out put